# Best way to take an independent snapshot or clipping of a particular DOM's state?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, clipboard, html

You know how if you copy a piece of rendered DOM from your browser's viewport to, say, MS Word, or one of Gmail's compose boxes, it will become a statically saved styled rendering of the content, not dependent on any external network-accessible resources? Also significantly, let's say that a button on the page was pressed which triggered an AJAX call for content which was filled into some div below the button upon receipt. If I copy this, paste it into a word document, it will stay in the word document even if the server at the ajax call's endpoint is taken offline and the page is refreshed in the browser.

I think a startup called clipboard.com had a similar concept, though it went under.

I'm wondering what folks can tell me about such functionality, and how it can be emulated or implemented, or even just better understood.

To clarify my question, what's word actually receiving when this happens, and how is it generated? I assume that the OS' clipboard is only capable of conveying textual content, and not any kind of objects or other rich intact data structures. So that just leaves the possibility of plain markup, if I'm not mistaken. Could I generate this markup myself from Javascript? And then what needs to happen on the receiving end? What does word do when it gets the markup? What other apps can receive such contents from a clipboard? What's curious is that if I paste it into notepad, it isn't markup, but just plain `textContent`.

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly in that term, that you want to paste contents of a webpage into a word document, and want the pasted part inside the document to update itself, so that it represents the current state of the webpage?

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat see my clarifying edition.

Comment: The OS clipboard can hold any type of data.  ASCII, binary, file handlers, etc.  When you copy from certain programs, you are copying "formatted data", which can be read by other programs.

Comment: @RocketHazmat where can I find documentation of this phenomenon?

Comment: @user3025492: I don't have any *concrete* documentation, but here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_(computing)#Data_formats